# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

When I execute my code below, this error message occurs:

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
> System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '='. "

And this is the code:

```
string position;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=free-pc\\FATMAH; Integrated Security=True; database=Workflow; ");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID=" + id.Text, con);

SqlDataReader Read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (Read.Read()==true)
{
    position = Read[0].ToString();
    Response.Write("User Registration successful");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Employee found.");
}

Read.Close();
```

What is causing this, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What is the text provided by the id `TextBox`?

Comment: It is **very important** not to concatenate input into SQL. Use parameters. Otherwise it will either just *fail* occasionally (there's hope there are no `O'Neil`'s in your company), or will act as a security hole (see: "bobby tables")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some problems with your code. First I advise to use parametrized queries so you avoid SQL Injection attacks and also parameter types are discovered by framework:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = @id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);
```

Second, as you are interested only in one value getting returned from the query, it is better to use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var name = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (name != null)
{
   position = name.ToString();
   Response.Write("User Registration successful");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No Employee found.");
}
```

The last thing is to wrap `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using` so any resources used by those will be disposed of:

```
string position;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=free-pc\\FATMAH; Integrated Security=True; database=Workflow; "))
{
  con.Open();

  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = @id", con))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);
  
    var name = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  
    if (name != null)
    {
       position = name.ToString();
       Response.Write("User Registration successful");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Employee found.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think your `EmpID` column is *string* and you forget to use `' '` in your value.

Because when you write `EmpID=" + id.Text`, your command looks like `EmpID = 12345` instead of `EmpID = '12345'`

Change your `SqlCommand` to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID='" + id.Text +"'", con);
```

Or as a better way you can (and should) always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID = @id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);
```

I think your `EmpID` column keeps your employee id's, so it's type should some numerical type instead of character.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID=@id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

use try-catch to see real error occurred on you

```
 try
{
  //Your insert code here
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
{
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sqlException.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

```
    private const string strconneciton = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Employees;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconneciton);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into EmployeeData (Name,S/O,Address,Phone,CellNo,CNICNO,LicenseNo,LicenseDistrict,LicenseValidPhoto,ReferenceName,ReferenceContactNo) values ( '" + textName.Text + "','" + textSO.Text + "','" + textAddress.Text + "','" + textPhone.Text + "','" + textCell.Text + "','" + textCNIC.Text + "','" + textLicenseNo.Text + "','" + textLicenseDistrict.Text + "','" + textLicensePhoto.Text + "','" + textReferenceName.Text + "','" + textContact.Text + "' )", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM [Employee] WHERE EmpID = @id", con))
```

put `[]` around table name ;)