# SQLException unhandled

Tags: c#, sql, exception, unhandled

I'm not sure whats wrong with my codes. When I run it, I get the error: SqlException was unhandled by user code. An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid object name 'ProductionPlanFabric'.

What does this mean?

Thank you :)

```
    private void displayPendingFabric()
    {
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                         ["ZZFashionIMSConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ProductionPlanID, FashionStyleID, FabricID, WarehouseID, PPStatus, PPFabricReqd, PPFabricIssued FROM ProductionPlanFabric WHERE PPStatus = 0 OR PPStatus = 2", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter daPPFabric = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet result = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        daPPFabric.Fill(result, "ProductionPlanFabric");
        DataView dvPPFabric = result.Tables["ProductionPlanFabric"].DefaultView; 
        conn.Close();

        gvPPFabric.DataSource = dvPPFabric;
        gvPPFabric.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: getting exception  on this `daPPFabric.Fill(result, "ProductionPlanFabric");` line ??

Comment: What's the message? wrap your code in try catch and get the message of exception to see what's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042952/an-exception-of-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-occurred-in-system-dat

Comment: It seems the db do not contain table `ProductionPlanFabric`, try to run this `SQL` in sql server, if success, check connection string

Comment: As mentioned try check the connection string, try connect with same values with SSMS and check also sql syntax in SSMS if the connection is succesful

Comment: just try `daPPFabric.Fill(result);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
conn.Open();
daPPFabric.Fill(result);
DataView dvPPFabric = result.Tables[0].DefaultView; 
conn.Close();
```