# Issue with the error 'Incorrect syntax near 'bit'. Must declare the scalar variable "@".' in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

When I try to submit data to my web application, I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'bit'. Must declare the scalar variable "@"

I checked, and I don't have 'bit' anywhere in the code. Four of the columns I'm writing to are now bit columns. This is based of the question I asked "[I'm trying write a Checkbox List to a Database, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796440/im-trying-write-a-checkbox-list-to-a-database-what-am-i-missing)."

I implemented the discussed changes and now I get an error and I wasn't sure if I needed to ask a new question, which shows the new code, or add to that question.

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Revocations.Default_2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div class="t_row_header">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="logo" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <h1>Transfer Revocations</h1>
        <div class="form-fields">

            <div class="form-group-left">
                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSchoolYear" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please enter  a    school   year."   SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    School Year:
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSchoolYear" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please enter a school  year     &gt;=    2017." Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="True" ValueToCompare="2017">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                </label>
                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>

                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStudentID" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please enter a     student ID."     SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    Student ID:</label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>

                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please enter a     first name."     SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    First Name:</label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>

                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please enter a     last name"     SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    Last Name:</label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>

                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRevokedSchool" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please   enter   the     revoking school" SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    Revoked School:</label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" CssClass="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>

                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRevocationDate" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please    enter  a     revocation date" SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    Revocation Date:</label>&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" TextMode="Date" CssClass="txtBox"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
            <!-- form-group-left -->

            <div class="form-group-right">
                <label>
                    Reason:<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem text="Academics"  Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem text="Attendance" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem text="Behavior"  Value ="3"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem text="Cooperative Relationship" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    <br />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNotes" CssClass="ErrorMessage" ErrorMessage="Please enter a    note."      SetFocusOnError="True">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    Notes:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" height="218px" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="InsideShadow"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" CssClass="ErrorMessage" />

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PPSS_RevocationConnection %>" DeleteCommand="SELECT 
       [SchoolYear]
      ,[Student_ID]
      ,[Last_Name]
      ,[First_Name]
      ,[Revoked_School]
      ,CAST([Revocation_Date] AS DATE) AS [Revocation_Date]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[Academics]
      ,[Attendance]
      ,[Behavior]
      ,[Cooperative Relationship]

  FROM [PPSS_Work].[Transfers].[Revocations]"
            SelectCommand="SELECT 
       [SchoolYear]
      ,[Student_ID]
      ,[Last_Name]
      ,[First_Name]
      ,[Revoked_School]
      ,CAST([Revocation_Date] AS DATE) AS [Revocation_Date]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[Academics]
      ,[Attendance]
      ,[Behavior]
      ,[Cooperative Relationship]

  FROM [PPSS_Work].[Transfers].[Revocations]"
            UpdateCommand="SELECT 
       [SchoolYear]
      ,[Student_ID]
      ,[Last_Name]
      ,[First_Name]
      ,[Revoked_School]
      ,CAST([Revocation_Date] AS DATE) AS [Revocation_Date]
      ,[Notes]
      ,[Academics]
      ,[Attendance]
      ,[Behavior]
      ,[Cooperative Relationship]

  FROM [PPSS_Work].[Transfers].[Revocations]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Revocations
{
    public partial class Default_2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Establish SQL Connection
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source = acctsql; Initial Catalog = PPSS_Work; Integrated Security = True") ;
            {
                // Write INSERT SQL statement
                SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [PPSS_Work].[Transfers].[t_Revocations](SchoolYear, Student_ID, Last_Name, First_Name,    Revoked_School,Revocation_Date,  Academics, Attendance, Behavior, [Cooperative Relationship], Notes) VALUES(@SchoolYear, @Student_ID, @First_Name, @Last_Name,    @Revoked_School,  @Revocation_Date,@Academics, @Attendance, @Behavior, @[Cooperative Relationship], @Notes)", sqlCon);

                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolYear", txtSchoolYear.Text);
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_ID", txtStudentID.Text);
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", txtFirstName.Text);
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", txtLastName.Text);
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Revoked_School", txtRevokedSchool.Text);
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Revocation_Date", txtRevocationDate.Text);
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text);

                foreach (ListItem item in chkbxlst1.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + item.Text, true);
                }

                sqlCon.Open();
                sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCon.Close();

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    txtSchoolYear.Text = "";
                    txtStudentID.Text = "";
                    txtFirstName.Text = "";
                    txtLastName.Text = "";
                    txtRevokedSchool.Text = "";
                    txtRevocationDate.Text = "";
                    chkbxlst1.Text = "";
                    txtNotes.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is causing these errors please?

Comment: One of your item.text is empty probably... Debug and see what's going in as a parameter...

Comment: You may want to count the number of parameters in the query and the number of parameters you are replacing with `AddWithValue`...

Comment: @VDWWD, If all 4 check boxes are checked, then the parameter count is good.  Would this error happen if less than 4 of the checkboxes where checked?  (When I ran it, all 4 check boxes were checked and every data field had data in it.)

Comment: @VDWWD, I don't see it as a duplicate as the parameter ID count matches up.

Comment: @KevinCook, Debugging shows all are selected when I submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problem because of the space in the parameter name `@[Cooperative Relationship]`, so to avoid the issue, at first replace the space with underscore in `Text` property of the list item `Cooperative Relationship` like below :

```
<label>
    Reason:<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem text="Academics"  Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem text="Attendance" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem text="Behavior"  Value ="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem text="Cooperative_Relationship" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <br />
</label>
```

And then modify the variable name `@[Cooperative Relationship]` to `@Cooperative_Relationship` in the `sqlCom` like below :

```
SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [PPSS_Work].[Transfers].[t_Revocations](SchoolYear, Student_ID, Last_Name, First_Name,    Revoked_School,Revocation_Date,  Academics, Attendance, Behavior, [Cooperative Relationship], Notes) VALUES(@SchoolYear, @Student_ID, @First_Name, @Last_Name,    @Revoked_School,  @Revocation_Date, @Academics, @Attendance, @Behavior, @Cooperative_Relationship, @Notes)", sqlCon);
```

Don't make any other changes in your existing code, then run the program, i hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the values you actually have in the chkbxlst1.Items collection, if you have one where item.Text is empty the following would produce that error:

```
foreach (ListItem item in chkbxlst1.Items)
{
if (item.Selected)
    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + item.Text, true);
}
```